# How to initialize REngine globally in C#.net?

Tags: c#, r, r.net

I am using R.Net and R.Net.Community packages in my c# project to enable R script. I have a c# class as follows:

```
foreach(var item in list)
{
  callR(item);
}
```

and a method in another class to run R script:

```
CallR(int item)
{
   //init the R engine                             
                REngine.SetEnvironmentVariables();
                engine = REngine.GetInstance();
                engine.Initialize();

  //Perform R
                engine.SetSymbol("data", item);
                engine.Evaluate("data<-data*data");

//engine.dispose
//Cannot use engine.dispose as re initialization of engine then, is not possible 
}
```

**Edit**
I have another third class which calls same R method. If I instantiate it in the class where I have made loop, then how to use that initialization in this class?

**Problem**:
This code works locally perfectly well, however on deploying it on server, it breaks and give exception: "library stats could not be loaded".

On searching deeper, I found [this](https://rdotnet.codeplex.com/discussions/463226) which says that initializing Rengine multiple times is causing this issue.

Therefore my question is how to initialize Rengine at application startup itself only once and use its instance in scenarios like my code above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could modify the CallR class to have a single instance of the REngine class and getting it through a method that initializes it only once e.g.

```js
public static REngine engine = null;
        public static REngine GetInitiazedREngine()
        {
            if (engine==null)
            {
                REngine.SetEnvironmentVariables();
                engine = REngine.GetInstance();
                engine.Initialize();
            }
            return engine;
        }

CallR(int item)
{
   //Get the initialized R Engine                             
                REngine initializedEngine=GetInitiazedREngine();

  //Perform R
                initializedEngine.SetSymbol("data", item);
                initializedEngine.Evaluate("data<-data*data");

//engine.dispose
//Cannot use engine.dispose as re initialization of engine then, is not possible 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think thak better practice would be to use Singletone pattern, something like this:

```
public class RNetEngine : IDisposable
{
  private bool _disposed;
  private REngine _rEngine;
  private static readonly object Lock = new object();

  private REngine Engine
  {
    get
    {
      if (_rEngine == null)
      {
        lock (Lock)
        {
        if (_rEngine == null)
          {              
            _rEngine = REngine.GetInstance();
          }
        }
      }
      return _rEngine;
    }
  }

  public void Evaluate(string expression)
  {
    Engine.Evaluate(expression);
  }

  public void Dispose()
  {
    Dispose(true);
    GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
  }

  protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
  {
    if (_disposed)
    {
      return;
    }
    if (disposing)
    {
      if (_rEngine != null && !_rEngine.Disposed)
      {
        _rEngine.Dispose();
      }
    }
    _disposed = true;
  }
}
```

This will keep you thread-safe and dispose when needed. I've got this used with Castle.Windsor Singleton lifestyle, so it's not static.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but I think once disposed, REngine cannot be re-initialized. Source: http://author-entry17.rssing.com/chan-9456546/all_p63.html

Comment: Right, but since it is a singletone, it's not going to be disposed while the application is running, and after that you have to free the resources you have used.

Comment: Oh ok I was not knowing about that..Thanks for help. Will surely try it.